# How to e-mail critical error and log the rest to prod.log

Tags: logging, symfony

Must be something really trivial but I can't make symfony2 to e-mail some errors (5xx) and simply log the rest (info level) into the file.

Here's what I have, almost an exact copy of [symfony2 cookbook example](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html).

```
# app/config/config_prod.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      grouped
        grouped:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, buffered]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            action_level: info
            level: debug
        buffered:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: error@example.com
            to_email:   error@example.com
            subject:    An Error Occurred!
            level:      debug
```

It does e-mail 5xx errors but neither 404 errors nor application info messages appear in prod.log

Comment: You are logging critical errors. 404 are level "error" by default, so setting the level to "error" should work.

Comment: That would make all the errors be e-mailed. I want 5xx (critical) e-mailed and the rest (including critical) logged. Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you want are two handlers which behave different? Then just use two handlers which are not connected:

```
# app/config/config_prod.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      streamed
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            action_level: info
            level: debug
        buffered:
            type:    buffer
            action_level: critical
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: error@example.com
            to_email:   error@example.com
            subject:    An Error Occurred!
            level:      debug
```

As you can see, removing the grouped handler, telling main to use stream and adding a action level to buffered "splits" the handling of stream and swift so you can define different actions for both.

With this loggers, you only get the error message emailed, not the full log like it was when there was a `fingers_crossed` type in place. If you want `fingers_crossed`, simply add another handler:

```
another_main:
    type:         fingers_crossed
    action_level: critical
    handler:      buffered
```

Of course you need to remove the `action_level` from buffered again.

Answer (score 1):

From the cookbook example:

> The mail handler is a fingers_crossed handler which means that it is only triggered when the action level, in this case critical is reached. It then logs everything including messages below the action level. The critical level is only triggered for 5xx HTTP code errors. The handler setting means that the output is then passed onto the buffered handler

Again from cookbook:

> If you want both 400 level and 500 level errors to trigger an email, set the action_level to error instead of critical.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't make it clear enough. I want only 5xx errors e-mailed. If I change the action_level on main handler I will end up with all errors in my mailbox. So I want 5xx in the e-mail and the rest in prod.log

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - well the behavior you are expecting should be default. You may try with a [custom listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081008/symfony2-logging-404-errors) to quickfix it.

Comment: hmm, even $this->get('logger')->info('blah') doesn't write anything to prod.log with the configuration I posted above