# how to handle exception 404 notfound

Tags: php, exception

I was planning to use symfony response object, but what is the simplest way to catch the exception and hook it up to the symfony exceptionhandler class.

Should I wrap the start of the application in a try/catch block or is there a more elegant/alternative way of doing things. Hook up an eventlistener maybe? How would I do that?

I am not looking to use big parts of the symfony framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Kernel Events.
you can see an exemple here:
[Symfony2 logging 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081008/symfony2-logging-404-errors)

and test the exception with  $exception->getStatusCode()

```
public function onKernelException(Event $event) {
    //Get hold of the exception
    $exception = $event->getException();
    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404)
    {
        //Do stuffs
    }

}
```

Comment: I will have to look into that